# DELETE request with file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, http-delete

file_get_contents method can do a GET or POST request. I am wondering if it is possible to do a DELETE request with this method. I tried like below but it doesn't seem to do a DELETE Request. I am also not getting any error or exception. Is this possible?

```
$postdata = http_build_query($param);
$opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'DELETE',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: You might need to use curl - I don't think it makes sense to use `file_get_contents` for HTTP requests that *don't return a body*.

Comment: What if my hosting doesn't provide curl? I want to know if this is possible with php without adding any extensions

Answer (score 3):

$result = file_get_contents(
    'http://example.com/submit.php', 
    false, 
    stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'DELETE' 
        )
    ))
);